# 'JestSerializer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SnapshotSerializerPlugin'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a file, in my CRA application, called setupTests.ts and it shows this warning on the createSerializer() Methode.
If i rename the file to a js file all compiles fine and the test runs.
Although if i add `"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]` as jest config in package.json it works fine. But i am curious if there is a way to make it work in that file.

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { createSerializer } from "enzyme-to-json";

expect.addSnapshotSerializer(createSerializer({mode: "deep",noKey: true}) );
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is the type definitions between `enzyme-to-json` and `"@types/jest"` seem to conflict so just do the following

```
//@ts-ignore
expect.addSnapshotSerializer(createSerializer({ mode: 'deep', noKey: true }));
```

I'm presuming this is your error (I don't see it specified in the question):

> (property) Options.noKey?: boolean | undefined
> Argument of type 'JestSerializer' is not assignable to parameter of type >'SnapshotSerializerPlugin'.
> Types of property 'print' are incompatible.
> Type '(CommonWrapper: CommonWrapper<{}, {}, Component<{}, {}, any>>, serializer: >JestSerializer) => Json' is not assignable to type '(val: any, serialize: (val: any) => >string, indent: (str: string) => string, opts: SnapshotSerializerOptions, colors: >SnapshotSerializerColors) => string'.
> Types of parameters 'serializer' and 'serialize' are incompatible.
> Type '(val: any) => string' is missing the following properties from type >'JestSerializer': test, printts(2345)

I ran into this because I was trying to use `enzyme-to-json` in a Creact-React-App typescript project where I don't have access to the jest config directly and I don't want to eject. The warning indicates the types `JestSerializer` and `SnapshotSerializerPlugin` are not compatible.

There is also an open issue at the `enzyme-to-json` repo which has been there for over a year so not sure if this is going to get resolved

https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json/issues/126

In my case the versions I was using of each were

```
"@types/jest": "^24.0.25"
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
```